# animate a google marker using javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Morning All.

I have a google maps v3 map, with 3 markers on.
a starting marker a finish marker and a movement marker.
as i get position updates i update the movement marker to match new position, but I would like to add a bounce to just that marker as an indicator that it has made a movement on the screen.

I know it can be done with a click listener, but I want to do it without user intervention if possible.
Any ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked [this google maps documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration). If you don't want to animate with user interaction, you can call "toggleBounce" function like below.

```
window.onload = function (){
    toggleBounce();
}

function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
      marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank You had a quick look and with a bit of tweaking it should do what i need thank you.